# Does't work fopen_s(&file, "filename", mode) in visual studio 2019 C_language

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So this is my first question here. If you could help me, that would be much appreciated. This code is about my thesis. I'm trying to write to a file and it works but trying to read another file is not reading.  I can't make it work. "file does not open" appears on the screen. Help me please, for read to file.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* myfile;
    errno_t errorcode = fopen_s(&myfile, "output.txt", "w");

    if (myfile == NULL)
    {
       printf("Error");
    }

    FILE* data; 
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&data, "C:\SA\input.txt", "r");

    //errno_t err = fopen_s(&data, "input.txt", "r");

    if(data==NULL)
    {
       printf("file does not open");
    }
return 0;
getchar();
}
```

Comment: `if(data==NULL);` You have an extra `;` here. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: 1) Your immediate problem is the extraneous `;`: `if(data==NULL);` 
 2) If "open" fails, you want to know *WHY*.  Two methods: print [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (or errno_t, as you did in one place above), or call [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) 3) `\` is a ["metacharacter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter): you need to "escape" it with another backslash: `"C:\\SA\\input.txt"`

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in your filename, `"C:\\SA\\input.txt"`

Comment: In C, '\' is the beginning of an escape sequence.  To get the actual '\' char, use two in a row, "C:\\SA\\input.txt"

Comment: Both `;` comments above explain the origin of problem but not why it does that:

Basically, the `;` makes your `if` meaningless, and makes your program execute the next statement no matter what. Basically it will display "file does not open" even though it has actually opened the file

Comment: It is unclear whether you are using C or C++. `iostream` isn't a C library.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should try using the `std::fstream` for file I/O.  The `std::fstream` is more forgiving about using various data types than `fprintf`.

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  Use `#include <iostream>` for C++ streams **OR** `#include<cstdio>` for C language streams.  No need to include both.

Comment: BTW, any statements after a `return` statement will not be executed.  Think about it.  The `return` causes execution to return at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code posted had 2 major issues:

- `"C:\SA\input.txt"` should be `"C:\\SA\\input.txt"` or simply `"C:/SA/input.txt"`. Microsoft's legacy systems use `\` as a path separator which must be escaped in C strings as `\\` (and in many other languages too). The traditional path separator on POSIX systems is `/` and it is also supported in Windows.
- `if(data==NULL);` is a test with an empty statement, hence nothing happens.
- Note that you should not use C++ headers such as `<iostream>` in a C program.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *myfile;
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&myfile, "output.txt", "w");
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                "output.txt", strerror(err));
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *data; 
    err = fopen_s(&data, "C:\\SA\\input.txt", "r");
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                "C:\\SA\\input.txt.txt", strerror(err));
        return 1;
    }
    getchar();  // keep terminal window open
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ece Uyar - this is an excellent summary.  Please be sure to "upvote" and/or "accept" if you find it helpful.  ALSO: note that "C++" <> "C"; chqrlie is using "C" syntax, and "C" header (.h) files.  Note, too, his "C" brace/indentation style.